# Utility to generate performance report of a NLP based text annotator

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, gate

I am trying to build a quality test framework for my text annotator. I wrote my annotators using [GATE](http://gate.ac.uk/)

I do have gold-standard (human annotated) data for every input document.

Here is list of gate resource for quality assurance [GATE Embedded API for the measures](http://gate.ac.uk/sale/tao/splitch10.html#x14-28100010.3.5)

So far, I am able to get performance matrix containing `FP,TP,FN, Precision, Recall and Fscores` using methods in
[AnnotationDiﬀer](http://gate.ac.uk/gate/src/gate/util/AnnotationDiffer.java)

Now, I want to dive deeper. I would like to look at individual FP,FN on per document basis.
i.e. I want to analyize  each FP and FN so that I can fix my annotator accordingly.

**I didn't see any function in any of GATE's classes such as AnnotationDiffer which returns `List<Annotation>` of FP or FN. They just return count of FP and FN**

```
int fp=annotationDiffer.getFalsePositivesStrict()
int fn=annotationDiffer.getMissing()
```

Before I go ahead and create my own utility to get `List<Annotation>` of FP and FN and couple of surrounding sentences, to create an HTML report per input document for analysis. I wanted to check if there is something like that already exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out how to get FP and FN annotations

```
List<AnnotationDiffer.Pairing> differ= annotationDiffer.calculateDiff(goldAnnotSet, systemAnnotSet);


    for(Annotation fnAnnotation:annotationDiffer.missingAnnotations)
    {
       System.out.println("FN=>"+fnAnnotation);
    }


    for(Annotation fpAnnotation:annotationDiffer.spuriousAnnotations)
    {
       System.out.println("FP=>"+fpAnnotation);
    }
```

Based on offsets of `fnAnnotation` or `fpAnnotations`, I can easily get the surrounding sentences and create a nice html report.